# Default property with multiple signatures

Tags: python

I'm trying to translate a VB.Net class to Python, but I don't know the best way to handle default properties. Multiple definations are used.

I want to provide a class for translation for as much languages as possible, as short as possible. My base language is VB.Net, where it works already. It's a syntax question, now for Python.

For example I want to let the developer code:

```
MyLabel.Text = L("MyDialog.MyLabel.Text")
```

The default language is used. But also…

```
MyLabel.Text = L("MyDialog.MyLabel.Text", "de")
```

…to force a language, but also…

```
MyLabel.Text = L("MyDialog.MyLabel.Text", "en", parameter1, parameter2…)
```

to add replacement parameters to it.

For replacement, the .Net style will be used, like "Hello {0}" where {0} will be replaced with parameter1. Nothing to worry in here. But parameters are variable. Can be none or 1 to n strings.

But how can I archieve this the best way in Python?
The original defination of the property is:

```
Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(Key As String, Language As String, ParamArray Args As Object()) As String
…

Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(Key As String, Language As String) As String
…

Default Public ReadOnly Property Item(Key As String) As String
…
```

L is a variable to the class instance. Because it is a default property, .Item is not required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no default properties in python.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a class definition that does, I think, what you want:

```
class L:
    # constructor
    def __init__(self, key, language="en", *args):
        self.key = key
        self.langauge = language
        for arg in args:
            # do something
```

So now, all of the following are valid:

```
a = L("MyDialog.MyLabel.Text")  # language is set to "en" by default
b = L("MyDialog.MyLabel.Text", "de")  # language is "de"
c = L("MyDialog.MyLabel.Text", "en", param1, param2)  # assuming param1 and param2 are defined
```

In the constructor definition (or in *any* function/method definition) you can specify the "default value" of a parameter by just saying `name=defaultvalue`. As per above, the python syntax for taking an arbitrary number of positional arguments would is `*args` - which, similar to VisualBasic, gets treated as a list once you get inside the function, that you have to iterate through or index into in order to use it.

(as a bonus - you can also specify a set of arbitrary *keyword arguments*, that you have to give in the form `key=value` rather than just in order. The syntax for doing this is `**kwargs` instead of (or in addition to) `*args`, and `kwargs` can be treated like a `dict` inside the function)

Comment: Interesting idea. But doesn't this method require to read all the data over and over again, for each string? This could be a performance issue.

Comment: What do you mean "read the data over and over again"? I don't see where that's a problem in this code (besides the `a` `b` `c` examples, but those are just examples). This is fairly idiomatic python (and besides, if you're looking for raw speed, why are you using python in the first place?)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mentoin it. In VB/C# I create an instance of the L class. Then, I call L.Load() to load a file (either external or from resources). It will get parsed and then applied to an internal dictionary, which .Item refers to. Full source (VB.Net): https://cutt.ly/Yi4Wok